# Is there a way to define a function that converts a value between same types?

Tags: function, types, proof, lean

i.e. Is it possible to define

```
example {α β : Type} (hab : α = β) (x : α) : β := sorry
```

From what I understand `Eq.subst a b` has type `∀ {α : Sort u} {motive : α → Prop} {a b : α}, a = b → motive a → motive b`, but the restriction that `motive` must return `Prop` seems an unnecessary restriction and hence does not suit my need very well.

Answer (score 2):

In Lean 3 it is called `eq.rec`/`eq.rec_on`. I guess, in Lean 4 it is called `Eq.rec`/`Eq.rec_on`.

Answer (score 0):

This is `Eq.cast` in Lean 4.

```
Eq.cast : {α β : Sort u_1} → α = β → α → β
```